# Piping sometimes does not lead to immediate output

Tags: bash, pipe, pipeline, buffering

I observed a few times now that `A | B | C` may not lead to immediate output, although `A` is constantly producing output. I have no idea how this even may be possible. From my understanding all three processes ought to be working on the same time, putting their output into the next pipe (or stdout) and taking from the previous pipe when they are finished with one step.

Here's an example where I am currently experiencing that:

`tcpflow -ec -i any port 8340 | tee second.flow | grep -i "\(</Manufacturer>\)\|\(</SerialNumber>\)" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}'`

What is supposed to happen:

I look at one port for tcp packages. If something comes it should be a certain XML format and I want to grep the Manufacturer and the Serialnumber from these packages. I would also like to get the full, unmodified output in a text file "second.flow", for later reference.

What happens:

Everything as desired, but instead of getting output every 10 seconds (I'm sure I get these outputs every ten seconds!) I have to wait for a long time and then a lot is printed at once. It's like one of the tools gobbles up everything in a buffer and only prints it if the buffer is full. I don't want that. I want to get each line as fast as possible.

If I replace `tcpflow ...` with a `cat second.flow` it works immediately. Can someone describe what's going on? And in case that it's obvious would there be another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Buffering. Pipes (and processes) often buffer input and output. You can try using things like `unbuffer` and `stdbuf` to "help" this but they don't always work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every layer in a series of pipes can involve buffering; by default, tools that don't specify buffering behavior for `stdout` will use line buffering when outputting to a terminal, and block buffering when outputting anywhere else (including piping to another program or a file). In a chained pipe, all but the last stage will see their output as not going to the terminal, and will block buffer.

So in your case, `tcpflow` might be producing output constantly, and if it's doing so, `tee` should be producing data almost at the same rate. But `grep` is going to limit that flow to a trickle, and won't produce output until that trickle exceeds the size of the output buffer. It's already performed the filtering and called `fwrite` or `puts` or `printf`, but the data is waiting for enough bytes to build up behind it before sending it along to `awk`, to reduce the number of (expensive) system calls.

`cat second.flow` produces output immediately because as soon as `cat` finishes producing output, it exits, flushing and closing its `stdout` in the process, which cascades, when each step finds its `stdin` to be at EOF, it exits, flushing and closing its `stdout`. `tcpflow` isn't exiting, so the cascade of EOFs and flushing isn't happening.

For some programs, in the general case, you can change the buffering behavior by using [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) (or [`unbuffer`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer), though that can't do line buffering to balance efficiency, and has issues with piped input). If the program is using internal buffering, this still might not work, but it's worth a shot.

In your specific case, though, since it's likely `grep` that's causing the interruption (by only producing a trickle of output that is sticking in the buffer, where `tcpflow` and `tee` are producing a torrent, and awk is connected to `stdout` and therefore line buffered by default), you can just adjust your command line to:

```
tcpflow -ec -i any port 8340 | tee second.flow | grep -i --line-buffered "\(</Manufacturer>\)\|\(</SerialNumber>\)" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}'
```

At least for [Linux's `grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (not sure if switch is standard), that makes `grep` change its own output buffering to line-oriented buffering explicitly, which should remove the delay. If `tcpflow` itself is not producing enough output to flush regularly (you implied it did, but you could be wrong), you'd use `stdbuf` on it (but not `tee`, which, per `stdbuf` man page notes, manually changes its buffering, so `stdbuf` doesn't do anything) to make them line buffered:

```
stdbuf -oL tcpflow -ec -i any port 8340 | tee second.flow | grep -i --line-buffered "\(</Manufacturer>\)\|\(</SerialNumber>\)" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}'
```

**Update from comments**: It looks like some flavors of `awk` block buffer prints to `stdout`, even when connected to a terminal. [For `mawk` (the default on many Debian based distros), you can non-portably disable it by passing the `-Winteractive` switch at invocation](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html#awk). Alternatively, to work portably, you can just call `system("")` after each `print`, which [portably forces output flushing on all implementations of `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-sidebar_002c-Controlling-Output-Buffering-with-system_0028_0029). Sadly, the obvious `fflush()` is not portable to older implementations of `awk`, but if you only care about modern `awk`, just use `fflush()` to be obvious and mostly portable.

Comment: Your answer comes pretty close and maybe in your system it's really grep that's doing the problems. For me it was awk as well though. Would you add the information with [the -wInteractive](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html)? Then I think I can mark this as solution. Thanks.

Comment: @erikb85: Ah. Looks like that is a `mawk` specific option; odd that it would block buffer when printing to `stdout` when `stdout` is connected to a terminal (that's decidedly non-standard). `gawk` seems to line buffer as expected for instance (I tested by just running `cat | awk '{print $1}'` and typing lines myself; my `gawk` always echoed back immediately). If you wanted portability, I'd suggest explicitly calling `fflush()` after the `print`, which would guarantee flushing from within `awk`, so you're not using non-portable switches.

Comment: @erikb85: Added notes on this to the bottom of the post. Of course, my _real_ solution would be to never use `awk`. ;-) Perl can do the same things as a one-liner (with a couple additional switches), and doesn't have the same portability issues, and since I learned it first, I mostly skip `awk`/`sed`.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should learn me some Perl. I always figured that for oneliners both would be equally powerful, so just learning one should be fine. But who can say without being expert in both.

Answer (score 2):

### Reduce Buffering

Each application in the pipeline can do its own buffering. You may want to see if you can reduce buffering in tcpflow, as your other commands are line-oriented and unlikely to be the source of your buffering issue. I didn't see any specific options for buffer control in tcpflow, though the `-b` flag for *max_bytes* may help in circumstances where the text you want to work with is near the front of the flow.

You can also try modifying the buffering of tcpflow using [*stdbuf* from GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html). This may help to reduce latency in your pipeline, but the man page provides the following caveats:

> NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard  streams  ('tee' does  for  example)  then  that  will override corresponding changes by 'stdbuf'.  Also some filters (like  'dd'  and  'cat'  etc.)  don't  use streams for I/O, and are thus unaffected by 'stdbuf' settings.

As an example, the following *may* reduce output buffering of tcpflow:

- `stdbuf --output=0 tcpflow -ec -i any port 8340 # unbuffered output`
- `stdbuf --output=L tcpflow -ec -i any port 8340 # line-buffered output`

unless one of the caveats above apply. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Also thanks. I found this answer not being specific enough to be marked as solution. But it's a very important addition to learn about that topic.